# cabal sandbox v. global package db

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

When installing inside a cabal sandbox, cabal will still use packages from the global package db (in particular, packages which came from the Haskell Platform). This can lead to install conflicts. Is it possible to configure cabal to ignore the global package db?

I see the corresponding feature has been implemented in `ghc` itself, via a `-no-global-package-db` option (see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5977), and `ghc-pkg` will ignore the global package db if you do not pass it the `--global` flag. Is there a way to configure cabal similarly?

Also, there's a closed issue against cabal implying the opposite behavior (rebuilding everything instead of using packages from the installed Haskell Platform), so I'm not sure if this behavior has changed over time; see https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass `cabal configure` the `--package-db` flag, documented like so:

> ```
> --package-db=DB                  Append the given package database to the
>                                  list of package databases used (to satisfy
>                                  dependencies and register into). May be a
>                                  specific file, 'global' or 'user'. The
>                                  initial list is ['global'], ['global',
>                                  'user'], or ['global', $sandbox],
>                                  depending on context. Use 'clear' to reset
>                                  the list to empty. See the user guide for
>                                  details.
> ```

So in particular, you can pass it `clear` and then pass it just the sandbox db.

This is all discussed in wonderful detail in the [Storage and Interpretation of Cabalized Packages](https://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/sicp.xhtml) article.